# get_previous_post() while accounting for sticky posts

Tags: posts, order, single, sticky-post

Let's say I have the posts `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. They are published in the following order:

```
1. foo
2. bar
3. baz
```

If I call `get_previous_post()` while on the `single.php` of `baz`, I'll get `bar`.

---

I set `bar` as sticky. Now, the posts are ordered like so:

```
2. bar
1. foo
3. baz
```

If I call `get_previous_post()` while viewing `baz`, I still get `bar`, because it's chronologically the previous post. However, in the actual "loop display" of the posts, `foo` is previous.

### Question

How do I get the "visually previous" post in WordPress?

**Edit:** Basically, I want `get_previous_post()` to process sticky posts as the newest, regardless of their post date.

Comment: So to make this clear: You are inside (the loop / a specific post) - meaning `get_post()` will return the viewed post - and want the first previous/next post that is not a sticky? Actually seems a bit complicated, as `get_adjacent_post()` doesn't take post ID into account, so you can't call it that easily on another post beside the current one ...

Comment: I have a listing on my `index.php` as described in my question. When I'm on the `single.php` of a post, I want to get the previous post as seen on the listing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this might be overcomplicating things a bit, but at least it should work (untested).

Just call the function like so

```
get_adjacent_without_sticky( get_the_ID(), true); // get previous post
get_adjacent_without_sticky( get_the_ID(), false); // get next post
```

This could have been solved easily, if `get_previous_post()` allowed for an ID to pass and not only run it in the context of the current post. Now you could copy the function code of `get_adjacent_post()` and adjust it to your needs, but I don't like messing directly with SQL inside WordPress, so using the common functions it should work like this:

```
function get_adjacent_without_sticky($id, $previous = true) {

    // get date of current post as reference
    $date = explode('.', get_the_date('d.m.Y', $id));
    $date_array = array(
        'day' => $date[0],
        'month' => $date[1],
        'year' => $date[2],
    );

    // for previous post we need the first post before current one
    if ($previous) {
        $order = 'DESC';
        $date_query = array(
            'before' => $date_array,
        );
    }
    // for next post we need the first post after current one
    else {
        $order = 'ASC';
        $date_query = array(
            'after' => $date_array,
        );
    }

    $args = array(
        // order sticky posts as regular ones
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        // get only the one post we want
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order' => $order,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'date_query' => $date_query,
    );

    // now run that query
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $result = get_post( get_the_ID() );
    } else {
        $result = NULL;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore original Post Data

    return $result;
}
```

Related topics:

- [sticky posts explained](https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts)
- [get posts after a certain date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778122/wordpress-query-posts-published-after-a-certain-date)

(My answer is bascially these two sources combined into a function.)

Comment: Actually, I _want_ to have sticky posts. I simply want to display the previous post as seen on the listing. By default, `get_previous_post()` returns the _chronologically_ previous post. It doesn't care whether the post is sticky or not. **I think this would explain it best:** If I set the **oldest** post as sticky, I want `get_previous_post()` to process it as the **newest**.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Then simply removing `'post__not_in' => $sticky,` should work, because `ignore_sticky_posts` will make them sorted regularly

Comment: @HristiyanDodov Have you seen the update/my last comment?